# Generate Rig is not scaled correctly

Tags: python, armature, bones

So at first I was having problems generating my metarig so I went into the preferences and turned on the auto run python scripts which fixed the problem, but then I ran into another one my generated rig isn't scaled accurately to fit my character or pre-existing metarig what am I doing wrong? I've tried everything so far and I'm still running into problems.[image]

Comment: What is the scale on your meta-rig?  Suggest applying scale to it before generating.

Answer (score 0):

Your mesh should have its scale and rotation applied before rigging.

Select your mesh objects in Object Mode and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Rotation, and redo it again for Scale.

When you manipulate Rigify's metarig, you should also have its scale and rotation applied the same way before generating the rig. If you already generated the rig, fix the metarig and then re-generate the rig.

You should avoid editing the rig object itself, many constraints might brake when doing that.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply scale the rig with mesh using <kbd>S</kbd> then apply scaling using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: I've tried that it doesn't work

Comment: @DillonAble could you upload your .blend file to be able to help you?